# Can I use mutate() to mimic a value i would join from a summarize() with dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I feel like there is a more elegant way with dplyr to recreate the following result of joining the results of a summarize call with mutate.

```
inner_join(iris, 
           iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarize(n = length(Species),
                                                    Mean.Sepal.Length = mean(Sepal.Length)),
           by = "Species")
```

When I feel there may be a way to use mutate in this way...

```
#iris %>% mutate(???)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for the `inner_join` You can just do `group_by()` with a `mutate()`.

```
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  mutate(n=n(), Mean.Sepal.Length=mean(Sepal.Length))
```